# VBA check if cells not empty - To Lastrow

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a macro I am trying to write. I have this macro behind the **worksheet event**, The Macro should check if ranges A2 , B2 , C2 are not empty , if there are not empty the macro is applied in cell D2. This should apply to the following rows A3,B3,C3 then apply macro to D3 and so. The macro is applied by **double clicking on the cell**

**Problem:** The code is not running the way i want it as above.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
        Select Case .Row
                Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
 Dim CheckCell As Range

    For Each CheckCell In Sheets("Dates").Range("A1,B2,C2").Cells
        If Len(Trim(CheckCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            CheckCell.Select
            MsgBox "Cell " & CheckCell.Address(0, 0) & " is empty. Click OK and populate it.", , "Missing Information"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next CheckCell

      .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username")

    End Select
                  End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not setting `cancel = true` to avoid 'in-cell editing'.

Comment: @Jeeped i will need to edit code for that as well thanks

Comment: Your code has **nothing** to do with your narrative.

Comment: @Jeeped thats why i think its not working the way it should.

Comment: The term *'apply macro'* does nothing but confuse the matter. Tell us what you want to actually do.

Comment: @Jeeped what i want to do is what is in the narrative. I think my incorrect code is what is confusing.

Comment: Try to use `""` that means Blank, with an If Statement inside a for loop `If .Range("NAME_YOUR_RANGE")<>"" Then` and input actions like `Range("D"&counter)="no blanks"` and `End If` That means if the cell in range is different from blank, then do something

Comment: @danieltakeshi thanks

Comment: the bad formatting of your code makes it very difficult to see what the code-flow is

Comment: All these close votes are for what? Here's the culprit `Len(Trim(CheckCell.Value)) = 0`. That's not the same as an empty cell, as @danieltakeshi states.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick nonsense; it seems that you want to run a sub procedure on every cell in column D where the cells in columns A, B and C are not blank.

That means you should be using a Worksheet_Change instead. Anytime something gets changed in columns A, B or C, use that row to run a sub procedure on column D.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:C"), Target.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim trg As Range, trgD As Range
        For Each trg In Intersect(Target, Range("A:C"), Target.Parent.UsedRange)
            If CBool(Application.CountA(Cells(trg.Row, "A").Resize(1, 3))) Then
                Set trgD = Cells(trg.Row, "D")
                MsgBox trgD.Address(False, False)
                trgD = Now
            End If
        Next trg
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is a simple MsgBox and Timestamp operation that you should have been able to research on your own in any of a thousand places.

Comment: The double was being used because the user has to double click on the cell.- Thanks for your help and advice. The code above was my attempt , i am not advanced VBA developer yet i am stilling starting out